# What is the analogue of Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(obj) in the Mockk library?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockk, mockk-verify

I want to switch to Mockk, but i cant find analogue of this method in Mockk
It doesn't work

```
verify (exactly = 0) { obj }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying it, is missing the method or variable

```
verify (exactly = 0) { obj.something }
```

Using the `exactly` zero approach would require

```
confirmVerified(obj)
```

To be sure nothing else was called.

The exact equivalent would be:

```
verify { obj wasNot Called }
```